# Launch a UICollectionView from a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a **Login Screen** and after the user successfully logs in I would I like to open my **Dashboard**, but the problem is I'm not able to do so.

I have researched a lot on the topic but every link points out where the `UICollectionView` opens a `UIViewController`, but not vice-versa.

**Approach 1**

```
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeScreen") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Approach 2**

```
let homeController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeScreen"))! as UICollectionView
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeController, animated: true)
```

I'm getting a black screen when I use the above code.

Comment: Does your `UICollectionView` have any cells at all? `UICollectionView` has a black background color by default.

Comment: What do you mean by launch a `UICollectionView` from a `UIViewController`?

Comment: @Losiowaty: Yes the UICollectionView has 6 cells with images and labels in it and background is set to **default**.

Comment: Can you show the code of your view controller with the collection view?

Comment: @Rikh : Launch = open like a window.

Comment: What is the class name of homeScreen View controller?

Comment: Have you properly implemented the dataSouce and delegate methods? Do they get called? Change the background color to clear color and check. Need a lot more context, regarding what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More often than not, the black screen you're experiencing is because your destination view controller (whether you push or present it) doesn't have `myCollectionView.delegate = self` and `myCollectionView.dataSource = self` in `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Utilities > Connections for segues that look like this:

[image]

This can create a black screen due to invalid connections. If you have any, disconnect the secondView by clicking the **x**.